# Calculate diff of values in a column under condition

Tags: pandas

I Have a DF with columns ['Region', 'Country', 'Year', 'Yearly_rank'].

I need to group by region and country and calculate for each country the change in 'Yearly_rank' between years 2016-2019

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Region': 'west europe', 'Country': 'Finland', 'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 1}, {'Region': 'west europe', 'Country': 'Denmark', 'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 2}, {'Region': 'west europe', 'Country': 'Norway', 'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 3}, {'Region': 'west europe', 'Country': 'Iceland', 'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 4}, {'Region': 'west europe',
```

'Country': 'Netherlands', 'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 5}, {'Region': 'west europe', 'Country': 'Switzerland', 'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 6}, {'Region': 'west europe', 'Country': 'Sweden',
'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 7}, {'Region': 'australia and new zealand', 'Country': 'New Zealand', 'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 8}, {'Region': 'north america', 'Country': 'Canada',
'Year': 2019, 'Yearly_rank': 9}, {'Region': 'west europe', 'Country': 'Austria', 'Year': 2019,
'Yearly_rank': 10}]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
cond = df["Year"].isin([2016, 2019])
change = df[cond].sort_values("Year").groupby(["Region", "Country"])["Yearly_rank"].diff()
df.assign(change=change).sort_values("change").groupby("Region").head(1)
```

Comment: I need just the years 2019 and 2016 solely, and I want to see which country in each region had the highest diff

Comment: So you want to calculate the change between 2016 and 2019 only?

Comment: Yes, and I want to see which country in each region had the greatest improvement in yearly rank.

Comment: See my edited answer. For future references. you need to add these details to your question. No one knows what you want except you.